# Why doesn't this throw an exception?

Tags: java, string

I have the following expression:

```
  String y = new String("a") + "b".substring(1,1) + "c".concat("d").toUpperCase();
```

The code compiles, and successfully prints "aCD".  My question is, why?

According to JLS, the operands should be evaluated from left to right before evaluating the expression.  This means that "b".substring(1,1) should throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException.  Instead it seems to just cast aside the value.

What is Java doing that causes the result of "aCD"?

*Note - I would never actually do this - I'm just trying to satisfy a curiosity.*

Comment: What makes you think that `"b".substring(1,1)` should throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: "if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex." - none of that is true.

Comment: length == 1. beginIndex == 1, endIndex ==1. Which rule is violated?

Comment: Try to isolate the "b".substring(1,1) to see the output

Comment: Perhaps you're mistaking substring wth .NET's verison, where the second parameter is the length? In java, it's the end index.

Answer (score 3):

It should not throw an exception because:

1. The beginIndex is not negative.
2. The endIndex is not larger than the length of the String.
3. The beginIndex is not larger than the endIndex.

To illustrate

```
"b" has a length of 1, a begin index of 0.

"b".substring(1,1);
```

1. The beginIndex is "1", and is not negative.
2. The endIndex "1" is not larger than the length of the string "1".
3. The beginIndex "1" is not larger than the endIndex "1".

I fully agree that this code is silly, because it guarantees the return of the string ""; however, there are many circumstances where these indexes are calculated, and under some of those circumstances, it makes a lot of sense to permit empty strings to be returned instead of exceptions.

Comment: This should have been obvious - I couldn't see the forest through the trees.

Comment: It kind of makes sense that it would throw an exception though, since the second index is exclusive and one might reason *"I can think of as inclusive, but decrease the value of the index by one."*, so that it means *"Start at index 1, end at index 0."*. But I guess 0.999... and 1.00... is the same number after all, so they are overlapping at that very point.

Comment: @kjl Not a problem at all.  I can easily see how one might get thrown off.  Java's end index not being inclusive of the end character permits one to not do the "subtract 1 from everything" logic that typically follows in string handling, but it does lead to some misinterpretations.  It's permitting the "startIndex" to effectively come at the "end" of string is another oddity, but again it helps avoid a lot of boilerplate code when parsing things.

Comment: @Gendarme You can't end at an index lower than you start at in Java.  Some languages permit this with a reversed sub-string; but fortunately, none of the ones I use heavily.  If I can end at "1", I should be able to start at "1" and get nothing, otherwise what's the "" string for?